# sbt-appengine: BindException: Address already in use

Tags: google-app-engine, sbt

I get this error from sbt when running

> appengine-dev-server

How can I tell sbt-appengine to tell Jetty to listen on a different port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
appengine-dev-server --port=8081
```

Comment: What about when using 'mvn appengine:devserver'? Any idea?